# How to continue form submission after an AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-post

I want to validate user entries on a WordPress post upon hitting the submit button, display an error message is there are problems, and submit the form if everything is OK. I have a PHP function that does the checking, returning `true` if data in `form_data` is OK, some error code otherwise. The following JavaScript issues the AJAX request, and was supposed to continue submitting the form upon successful checking, but it doesn't:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#post').submit(function() {

                var form_data = jQuery('#post').serializeArray();
                var data = {
                    action: 'ep_pre_submit_validation',
                    security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'pre_publish_validation' ); ?>',
                    form_data: jQuery.param(form_data),
                };
                var proceed = false;
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    if (response.indexOf('true') > -1 || response == true) {
                        proceed = true;
                    } else {
                        alert("Error: " + response);
                        proceed = false;
                    }
                });
                jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                return proceed; //breakpoint here makes the code run
            });
        });
```

The code is adapted from a [WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/15627/10406), which originally didn't work for me as the form didn't get submitted. I found out that if the jQuery function bound to `.submit()` returns true, the form should be submitted, so that's what I tried to implement. With the code above, it doesn't seem to work at first (form doesn't get submitted when there are no errors), but upon close inspection with Firebug `proceed` seems to get the right result if a breakpoint is inserted at the `return proceed` line. It works as intended with valid data **only** if I wait it out a bit upon hitting the breakpoint, and then continue execution. If there are errors, the alert is issued without a problem.

What is the best way to handle this?

**EDIT**

Based on @Linus answer below, the following code works with both valid and invalid data:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('#post').submit(function() {
                if(jQuery(this).data("valid")) {
                    return true;
                }

                var form_data = jQuery('#post').serializeArray();
                var data = {
                    action: 'ep_pre_submit_validation',
                    security: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'pre_publish_validation' ); ?>',
                    form_data: jQuery.param(form_data),
                };
                jQuery.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
                    if (response.indexOf('true') > -1 || response == true) {
                        jQuery("#post").data("valid", true).submit();
                    } else {
                        alert("Error: " + response);
                        jQuery("#post").data("valid", false);

                    }
                    //hide loading icon, return Publish button to normal
                    jQuery('#ajax-loading').hide();
                    jQuery('#publish').removeClass('button-primary-disabled');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: You can't - not in this manner.

Some background: The callbacks you supply as arguments to functions such as `$.post` are executed asynchronously. This means that you will `return proceed` *before* your success callback has been executed, and `proceed` will always be `false`. With your breakpoint, if you wait until the success callback has executed, `proceed` will be `true` and all will be well.

So, if you want to submit the form after your ajax request has finished, you *must* submit it using javascript. This is pretty easy with jQuery, just do a jQuery `$.post` with `data: $("yourForm").serialize()` and `url: yourForm.action`.

This is basically what you already are doing, you just have to repeat that call to the URL to which you actually want to post the data.

**EDIT:**

Another way would be to set an attribute on your form, say `valid`, and in your `submit` handler check that:

```
jQuery("#post").submit(function() {
    if($(this).data("valid")) {
        return true;
    }
    // Rest of your code
});
```

And in the success callback for your validation ajax request you would set/clear that attribute, and then submit:

```
$("#post").data("valid", true).submit();
```

**EDIT:**

You also want to do your "ajax-loading"/button enabling inside the callback for `$.post` for the same reasons stated above - as it is, they will happen immediately, before your ajax call returns.

Comment: Brilliant solution! I struggled a bit at first, but I realized afterwards that it wasn't working because within WordPress jQuery has to be called as `jQuery` and not `$`...

Comment: Wow, you just saved my living room window, my computer and my last shred of patience. I couldn't understand (and still don't) why an ajax event can't block and then signal completion and allow regular form processing to occur. This worked, but I can't fathom why this scenario didn't crop up when the powers that be tested this.

Answer (score 6):

Bind your button to a validation function instead of submit. If it passes validation, call submit().

Comment: You mean to do the validation with JQuery Validate or something like that? Can I do an Ajax call with it?

Comment: Instead of a submit button, use a regular button to make your AJAX call. Submit the form in-code when you want to submit it.

Comment: Gotcha. I ended up doing that as well, and it actually solved the handling of saving drafts but not publishing posts as well. Thanks!

Comment: I think this is the easiest and best way after trying for 3 days, change your submit button to normal "a href" button and control your form with $(document).ajaxComplete(function() { //to do }); call $(#your-form-id).submit(); to submit

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress has its own mechanism to process Ajax requests, using wp-admin/wp-ajax.php. This allows you to run arbitrary code on either side of the Ajax boundary without having to write the back and forth status-checking code and all that. Set up your callbacks and go....

Answer (score 1):

The real question is - why are you doing validation server-side?  Why can't you load in the validation criteria before  - as the post is being written?  Then your validation can happen real-time and not on-submit.

jquery.post is performed asynchronously, which means the JS will continue before it gets the reply.    You're stuck with Diodeus's answer - bind the button to validtion which then submits the form (which makes it not degrade well), or change your $.post to ajax and turn off async, which will force it to wait for response before proceeding...possibly locking up JS on your page until it times out.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: ajaxurl,
    async:false,
    data: data,
    timeout:3000,
    success: function(){

    }
});
```

Comment: Good point about the server-side validation; I was just thinking about this now. I needed to make sure that a post with invalid/incomplete data does not get published, that's why I thought server-side was the way to go. Perhaps disable the submit (Publish) button while there are unmet requirements? What about if JavaScript is disabled by the user? Would this add a lot of overhead?

Comment: Front-side validation is very light on overhead.  if ($('your field').val().length < xxx){ $('#error').html('too short');return false;}    Since a VERY low percentage of users have js disabled anymore, the good practice is to do all validation front-side, then, run back-end checks on the page that processes the post as a fallback.  If it gets past front end, you can still bounce them back to the page with an error message.