# Ajax works on return true, but not false

Tags: jquery, ajax

I don't know exactly why this happens, here is some of the code:

```
function submit_edit(url) {
    var value = $('#clicked').val();
    var staff_ID = $('#staff_id').val();

    if (value == 'Delete') {
        url = url + '/Delete/' + staff_ID;
        alert(url);
        myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
            check_url(url);
        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (value == 'Submit') {
        alert(url);
        myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Submit Changes', function (event) {
            //event.preventDefault();
            check_url(url);

        });
        return false;
    }
    else if (value == 'Cancel') {
        url = url + '/Cancel';
        myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Cancel Changes', function () {
            check_url(url);
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

The `delete` and `cancel` statements work. But when I hit submit, it doesn't process the form. Granted the other two don't use any of the `checkbox` inputs. The script will work as soon as I turn the `return false;` to `return true;`, but it will redirect it... which isn't what I want. This is the closest I've gotten so far. You can request extra code if need be, I will supply it. I do appreciate all answers and feedback!

**Update**

---

Here is the requested code for the `check_url()`

```
    function check_url(recieve_url) {
    if (recieve_url == undefined || recieve_url == null) {
        alert("recieve_url is not set!");
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : recieve_url,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (result) {
            //alert(result['bg'] + result['message'] + result['caption'])

            myApp.alert(result['message'], result['title'], function () {
                if (result['redirect'] != null || result['redirect'] != undefined){
                    window.location = "<?php echo $this->url;?>"+result['redirect'];
                }
            });
                //myApp.alert(result['message'], result['title']);


        },
        error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            myApp.alert(xhr.responseText);
            myApp.alert(recieve_url);
            myApp.alert(thrownError);
        }

    })

}
```

Comment: you can't do the return true AND have a custom confirm dialog. there is no other way than manually submitting the form when you want it submitted.

Comment: Where is the AJAX, in the `check_url()` function?

Comment: Maybe have a look at: [How to continue form submission after an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9331042/218196)

Comment: Im trying to keep the `return false;`

Comment: @Barmar, I added the code to the question.

Comment: I don't understand, where do you expect it to process the form? Returning false from an event handler means you don't want the default action to take place, it's the old way of doing `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: I would like to have it submit just like the `delete` one but for some reason it doesn't want to post the variables.